# Files outside of Apache document root

Tags: apache, security, phpmyadmin, document-root

My current document root contains only my files which I want to be public. Tools like phpmyadmin are outside of my document root:

```
(...)
----/phpMyAdmin/
----/htdocs/
--------(...)
------------/public/ (document root)
----------------(all my files)
```

However, I can still access phpmyadmin by navigating to localhost/phpmyadmin. I'm assuming this is some kind of option in my server settings (a symbolic link?), and I'm fine with this. But I'd like to be able to rename the folder and restrict access to it, as well as view a list of any other files outside of my document root which are accessible.

Can anyone explain to me how/why this is happening and how I can configure it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some hunting, I found my own answer. In my situation, the alias wasn't located in httpd.conf, but in extra/httpd-xampp.conf:

```
Alias /phpmyadmin "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
```